# How to implement java Overriding on Instantiation in C#?

Tags: java, c#, overriding

I am translating a sample android application from java to C# and i'm stuck on this piece of code.

```
CommandQueued  mConferenceQueue = new CommandQueued( "ConferenceManager" )
{
    protected void onHandleCommandMessage( Message msg )
    {
        onConferenceEvent( msg );
    }
};
```

After a couple of research, it seem that java allow overriding of class methods at instantiation.

**Can anybody tell me how it could be translated in c# ?**

Comment: Just declare a class derived from CommandQueued where you override onHandleCommandMessage() then create an instance of that class instead of the base class CommandQueued.

Comment: Why not define another class which drives from the base class and override in it?

Comment: Side question: I don't understand...shouldn't be easier to first learn C# and then to rewrite an existing application written in another language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
public class CommandQueued
    {
        protected virtual void onHandleCommandMessage(Message msg)
        {
            //onConferenceEvent(msg);
        }
    }

    public class DerivedCommandQueue : CommandQueued
    {
        protected override void onHandleCommandMessage(Message msg)
        {
            //..
        }
    }
```